# perl match this but not that pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to get string between `"`:

```
my $a = 'echo "this is John."; # ok ';
$a =~ /"([^"]*)"/;
print $1;
```

This works, but it can't handle a string with `\"` inside:

```
my $a = 'echo "this is \"John\"."; # ok ';

# How to print: this is \"John\".
```

How do I get a string between `"` but not `\"`?

Comment: How do you can a string? Isn't this more of a question for cooking.stackexchange.com? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex like below.

```
$a =~ /(?<!\\)"(.*?)(?<!\\)"/;
```

or

```
/(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*".*?(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*"/;
```

or

```
/(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*"(?:\\\\|\\"|[^\\"])*"/;
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hJ5rC9/1), [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/hJ5rC9/4)

`(?<!\\)"` would match the double quotes only if it's not preceeded by a backslash character.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to ignore embedded quotes, [`Text::ParseWords`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html) -- a core module in Perl 5 -- offers a simple way to deal with it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $s = 'echo "this is \"John\"."; # ok ';
my @x = grep { defined and /^"/ } quotewords(" ", 1, $s);
print Dumper \@x;
```

Note that you should avoid using `$a` and `$b`, as they are reserved by the `sort` function.

In this code I simply split on whitespace, and ask that quoted fields are intact. Since we are only interested in the quoted string, I remove the rest by using `grep`.

Comment: Perhaps `map { defined && /^"(.*)"/s ? $1 : () }` instead of grep.

Comment: @Сухой27 Why would I do that?

Comment: This gives the desired output.

Comment: Check `this is \"John\".` vs `"this is \"John\".";`

Comment: That is odd, never seen that behaviour before. Not sure why it would keep the semi-colon.

Comment: Semicolon plus two double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to match an escape sequence or a non-special character: `(?:\\.|[^\\"])*`

All together, we get:

```
my $a = 'echo "this is John."; # ok ';
$a =~ /^ (?:\\.|[^\\"])* " ( (?:\\.|[^\\"])* ) "/xs;
print $1;
```

Comment: @ikegami did you failed to find the failure done by this code?

Comment: @Avinash Raj, Anchoring is needed, of course. Added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

**`([^"]*):`** doesn't capture `\"` because the pattern means

> capture anything that is not  `"`.

So for you to make it work, you can match everything within `""` using `"(.*)"`. Then capture `group 1`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gT9uU3/9)

Comment: This does not work if there are multiple quotes in the string, because `.*` is greedy.

Comment: I answered with regards to his question. He needed a pattern to match everything within the first and last quotes. so if there are multiple quotes within the first and last quotes, it would  still match it

Comment: `foo "the name is \"John\"", and the other name is \"Bob\"` would give incorrect answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use following also:

$a =~ /.*?"(.*?.)"/;